# Why does NuGet "Get-Package -ListAvailable" return nothing?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm new to NuGet. I have MS Visual Web Developer Express 2010

If I type: Get-Package -ListAvailable

nothing happens except that the new prompt is presented.

In the drop-down, I tried Source = "All", and "Official Package Source"

Answer (score 0):

Odd. What happens if you open the NuGet Package Manager dialog (right click the project) and go to the Online tab ?

Comment: Solved. Despite the fact that I was experimenting with a newly downloaded NuGet, it was in fact out-of-date (possibly due the fact that the NuGet site is not exactly new-user friendly). An upgrade to the latest version solved the problem.